# How to check if stream is empty in C++?

Tags: c++

I hava data format such as: `int n`, then `n` times two ints in braces separated by `;`
Example: 2 (1;1) (0;3)

I read first `n` and then read this thing in braces `n` times

How can I ensure that there is nothing left in stream or throw exception otherwise?

I tried to do like this:

```cpp
if (iss.rdbuf()->in_avail() != 0) {
    // do something
}
```

Type of `iss` is `std::stringstream`. But it does not work if there are spaces after last symbol I read.

How can I check that stream (`stringstream` actually, but does not really matter) is empty?

Comment: The only way to see if the stream is at the end is to try to read from it.

Comment: Can you confirm that your goal is to throw if the input is, e.g. `2 (1;1) (0;3)  abc`, but not throw if it's `2 (1;1) (0;3)   `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the `>>` operations on the stream are a truthy (bool) expression indicating success. Or, more precisely, the `>>` operator returns a reference to the stream itself. And streams overload the bool cast to indicate if a stream is in a good or bad state.

So if the result of attempting to parse something from the stream is false, then you can assume the stream is empty.

To parse your example, here's some code below. Note. I don't actually validate the parenthesis or semi-colon. I just replace all the non-digit chars in the `"(0:3)"` expressions with whitespace so that it becomes `" 0 3 "`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// parse "(0:3)" from a stream and return {0,3} as an integer pair
bool readItem(std::istream& stream, std::pair<int, int>& p)
{
    std::string item;

    if (stream >> item)
    {
        // anything not a digit gets converted to whitespace
        std::string s;
        for (char c : item)
        {
            s += (std::isdigit(c)) ? c : ' ';
        }

        std::istringstream ssItem(s);
        int x = -1;
        int y = -1;
        if ((ssItem >> x) && (ssItem >> y))
        {
            p.first = x;
            p.second = y;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    const std::string s = "2 (1;1) (0;3)";
    std::istringstream ss(s);

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> items;
    int n;

    if (ss >> n)
    {
        std::pair<int, int> p;
        for (int i = 0; (i < n) && readItem(ss, p); i++)
        {
            items.push_back(p);
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I thought of it, but there a way to do it with some functions or methods in std? To me it seems like not a good practice

Comment: @mcyrill - did you consider using the `peek()` function on the stream? https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/

Answer (score 3):

You can skip whitespace using the `std::ws` manipulator:

```
iss >> std::ws;
```

It will stop reading either if it encounters a non-whitespace character (in which case the stream will be `good()`), or if a failure occurs. At this point you can check if it reached the end of the stream with the `eof()` call. It can be combined to a one-liner as follows:

```
if((iss >> std::ws).eof())
```

If you want to check for the end of the stream right away (without skipping whitespace), you can do it through a call to `get()` or `peek()`:

```
if(iss.peek() == EOF)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is quite simple:

```
std::ifstream ifs("file.txt");

while(true) {
    int amount=0;
    if (!(ifs >> amount)) {
       break; // or whatever you want to do for end of stream
    }
    for (int i=0; i < amount; ++) {
       // read your data in brackets with
       // ifs >> 
    }
}
```

Note, end of stream is not exceptional situation, this is the expected result, so no need to throw exception when you are done with reading, just finalize it.