# string stream of ints trailling with a space/carriage return/tab results in re-streaming of last int in C++

Tags: c++, stringstream

this error occuars with any (or mix) of mentioned characters in title but I will talk about spaces for easier reading.

A textfile names input.txt conatins space seprated ints, ex:

```
2 3 
4 1 
5 4 1
```

each has line has a trailling space
I need to diffrinacte between lines so I use getline

```
int main()
{
    string input;
    stringstream ss;
    ss.clear();ss.str("");
    int  no_lines = 3;
    int tmp;

    for(int i = 0; i < no_lines; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, input);
        ss.clear();
        ss.str(input);
        while(!ss.eof())
        {
            ss >> tmp;
            cout << tmp << ' '; 
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

and I ran the program with `a.out < input.txt`
expected output is the same as input.txt but rather I get this:

```
2 3 3 
4 1 1 
5 4 1 1
```

every last int is reapeated.

Comment: Looks like you need to trim trailing spaces from `input` - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/how-to-trim-an-stdstring

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76138990/1607937 - `ss >> tmp` returns a bool.

Comment: @Den-Jason Trailing spaces are irrelevant, `operator >>` ignores any whitespace until first non-whitespace character (or end of data). The problem is with using `.eof()`, as the duplicate states. And saying that `ss >> tmp` returns a `bool` is an oversimplification - it returns `ss`, but streams in C++ are defined to be convertible to `bool` for convenience.

Comment: I ended up using !(ss >> tmp).eof() as pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76139060/12189479 given by Den-Jason
but Yksisarvinen helped me understand it more.